# C: Using Fork() and Pipe() to add numbers in child processes

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I'm trying to send numbers from a file to child processes with `fork()` and `pipe()`, which the child processes should add and send back to the parent process which will then add the child sums to get a total sum.

For a simplified version of that problem, I've got an Array of 4 numbers, and am only using 1 Child process (2 pipes).

I'm having difficulties seeing where control in my program goes, which makes it hard for me to troubleshoot what else is going wrong.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int numChildProcesses = 1;
int testArray[4] = {2,7,9,4};

printf("Will use 1 child process; %d pipes.\n", numChildProcesses*2);
int fd[numChildProcesses*2][2]; //parent and child

int val = 0, len, i;

// create all the descriptor pairs we need
for (i=0; i<numChildProcesses*2; ++i) // 2 pipes // parent + child
{
    if (pipe(fd[i]) < 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to allocate pipes.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

for (i=0;i<numChildProcesses;i++)
{

    //CHILD/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        int total = 0, xCount = 0;

        while (xCount < 4)
        {
            // wait for parent to send us a value
            len = read(fd[i][0], &val, sizeof(val));
            if (len < 0)
            {
                perror("Child: Failed to read data from pipe.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else if (len == 0)
            {
                // not an error, but certainly unexpected
                fprintf(stderr, "Child: Read EOF from pipe\n");
            }
            else // Successfully read from Parent
            {
                total += val;
                xCount += 1;
                printf("Child: Recieved %d\tTotal: %d\tCount: %d\n", val, total, xCount);

            }
        }

        // send the value back to the parent
        printf("Child: Sending %d back\n", total);
        if (write(fd[i][1], &total, sizeof(total)) < 0)
        {
            perror("Child: Failed to write response value");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    //PARENT/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (fork() > 0)
    {
        int total = 0;

        // send array to child as well as starting point
        printf("\nParent: Sending numbers to child\n");
        //if (write(fd[i][1], 0, (fileNumbers/numChildProcesses)*5) != sizeof((fileNumbers/numChildProcesses)*5));
        if (write(fd[i][1], &testArray, sizeof(testArray)) != sizeof(testArray))
        {
            perror("Parent: Failed to send value to child ");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // now wait for a response
        len = read(fd[i][0], &val, sizeof(val));
        if (len < 0)
        {
            perror("Parent: failed to read value from pipe");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (len == 0)
        {
            // not an error, but certainly unexpected
            fprintf(stderr, "Parent: Read EOF from pipe\n");
        }
        else
        {
            // report what we received
            total += val;
            printf("Parent: Received %d\tTotal: %d\n", val, total);
        }

        // wait for child termination
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

}

---

My output is as follows:

```
Will use 1 child process; 2 pipes.

Parent: Sending numbers to child
Parent: Received 2      Total: 2
Child: Recieved 7       Total: 7        Count: 1
Child: Recieved 9       Total: 16       Count: 2
Child: Recieved 4       Total: 20       Count: 3
```

Furthermore, if I try something like `printf("%d", fork());` as soon as I enter my `for()` loop to see what it taking control, it gets a little crazy. It acts like using `fork()` affects the way the program runs, as if it is a `pop()` or something of the sort.

---

Anyways, thank you for any insight you can offer.

-Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forking too much. You're calling `fork()` twice in your loop: once in your "child" `if`, and one in your "parent" `if`. And then even more when you add your `printf("%d", fork());`.

You should only call `fork()` once per loop. Save the return value in a variable, then print/check it.

Comment: Thank you.  Now my output is cleaner, but parent still only calls once and all the other loops go straight to child. After 1 parent and 3 child outputs, the program hangs. Any ideas on that?

Comment: You create 2 pipes, but parent and child are reading and writing the same pipe -- you never use the second one. Your parent's read is stealing the first value from the values it just wrote, leaving the child with one value too little; so it never quits. You should use pipe `2*i` for communication one way, and `2*i+1` for the other way.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That's cleared it up for me. However, I'm wondering why you didn't suggest that i use `i` and `i+1` instead of `2i` and `2i+1`

Comment: Because when you start using more child processes, you'd be using pipes 0 and 1 for the first loop, then 1 and 2 for the second, 2 and 3 for the third, and so on. And we've already seen the problems with using the same pipe from several processes. Using `2 * i`, you'll have 0 and 1 for the first loop, 2 and 3 for the second, 4 and 5 for the third. You could also use `i` and `i + numChildProcesses`, giving you (if you had, say, 4 numChildProcesses) 0 and 4 in the first iteration, 1 and 5 in the second, 2 and 6 in the third...